# Nginx how to add cookie only once under path /

Tags: nginx, cookies

I use nginx as a reverse proxy to server a website, every request will be transferred to backdoor application by nginx, and once a response is generated, it will be replied to client by nginx. What I want to do is add a custom cookie when nginx get the response from backdoor application.

Suppose My domain is xxx.com, from the user's view, what I want it when he visits any page of my site, his browser will get a cookie username looks like the following:

[image]

## First try

My nginx conf is:

```
location / {
    add_header Set-Cookie "username=$http_id; Domain=.xxx.com; Path=/" always;
}
```

When visits every page of my site, nginx will add the username combine with a new path(path is not /, it is $uri variable in nginx), then there are so many duplicate cookie username under my site(they are only different at path).  Looks like:

[image]

## Second try

I change the conf to:

```
location = / {
    add_header Set-Cookie "username=$http_id; Domain=.xxx.com; Path=/" always;
}
```

This time, there are no duplicate cookie item, but one must visit xxx.com/. If one just visit some pages but not the /,cookie will not be set.

## Question

What conf can let nginx to write cookie just once when user visit any page of my site?

Comment: Post your full nginx config

Comment: I am very sure that other configs are nothing important.

Comment: Okie so I assume you are not using `add_header` anywhere else?

Comment: Yes, I only use add_header here.

Comment: Then move it to the `server` block outside of the location. This should work

Comment: I have tried, nginx will add the username combine with a new path(path is not /, it is $uri variable in nginx).  just like the first image

Comment: I just tested and it works fine for me. Make sure you clear all existing cookies.